# Delete text before and after a certain string in email (up to a certain word)

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I am looking to create a VBA macro (from Excel) that searches for an email with an account number in the body, and deletes all other table elements within that email except for the row with my element I specified.

For example, please see the attachment below. Let's say the number I searched for was the "222222222222" number. I would need the VBA code to keep the table headers, delete all of the accounts that are not the "22222222222" (so all of the 1111 accounts) while also keeping the holding quantity. Is there code that can delete all text after "2222222222" but stop deleting at the word "Term"? On that token, can it start deleting after the word "Deadline" but stop deleting when it reaches the "222222..." account?

[image]

Please let me know if there are any methods I can focus on to achieve this.

Thank you!

(P.S. these emails vary in length, and many of them are received every day. Additionally, I already have the code that can search and open the email by searching for text. I just can't figure out how to delete this extraneous stuff I'm not looking for.)

I have attached my relevant code to search and open the email below:

```
Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
Dim olNs As Namespace
Dim Fldr As MAPIFolder
Dim olMail As Outlook.MailItem
Dim i As Integer
Dim olMsg As Outlook.MailItem
Dim r As Range
Dim strLocation As String
Dim o As Outlook.Application
Dim strbody As String
Dim objInspector As Object

Set r = ActiveSheet.Buttons(Application.Caller).TopLeftCell
Range(Cells(r.Row, r.Column), Cells(r.Row, r.Column)).Select

Set olApp = New Outlook.Application
Set olNs = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set Fldr = olNs.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Folders(" Notifications Macro")
i = 1


For Each olMail In Fldr.Items
If InStr(olMail.body, ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, ColumnOffset:=-3).Value) <> 0 Then
olMail.display

If InStr(olMail.body, "Mandatory Event: No Responses Required for this") Then
    strbody = "<BODY style=font-size:11pt;font-family:Calibri>Team,<br><br>" & _
              "Please see the notice below regarding " & _
              ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, ColumnOffset:=-2).Value & _
              ".<br><br> This is for informational purposes and no action is required.<br><br>" & _
                "Thank you!"

With olMail.Forward
.To = ActiveCell.Offset(ColumnOffset:=-1)
.display
SendKeys ("%")
SendKeys ("7")
 'Call Sleep
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:03"))
.HTMLBody = strbody & "<br>" & .HTMLBody
.HTMLBody = Replace(.HTMLBody, ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, ColumnOffset:=-3).Value, "<FONT style=" & Chr(34) & "BACKGROUND-COLOR: yellow" & Chr(34) & ">" & ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, ColumnOffset:=-3).Value & "</FONT>")


End With
End If

If InStr(olMail.body, "Warning: Response Required") Then
    strbody = "<BODY style=font-size:11pt;font-family:Calibri>Team,<br><br>" & _
              "Please see the notice below regarding " & _
              ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, ColumnOffset:=-2).Value & _
              ".<br><br> If the client wishes to make an election, they will need to call the corresponding team before the deadline indicated on the notice.<br><br>" & _
                "Thank you!"

With olMail.Forward
.To = ActiveCell.Offset(ColumnOffset:=-1)
.display
SendKeys ("%")
SendKeys ("7")
 'Call Sleep
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:03"))
.HTMLBody = strbody & "<br>" & .HTMLBody
.HTMLBody = Replace(.HTMLBody, ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, ColumnOffset:=-3).Value, "<FONT style=" & Chr(34) & "BACKGROUND-COLOR: yellow" & Chr(34) & ">" & ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, ColumnOffset:=-3).Value & "</FONT>")


End With
End If

End If
Next

End Sub
```

The code may look confusing, but all it does is it searches a specific outlook folder for mail containing a certain value (in cell A1... in this case... 222222222222) and then opens the email, forwards the email, and highlights the account number (2222222222) within the email.

Ideally, a snippet of code that could delete all text before the "22222222" account number up until the word "Deadline" in addition to code that could delete text after the "2222222" number until it hits the word "Term". The issue is that I would also need the quantity holding to stay, and since this number can really be anything it's difficult for me to think of how to do this.
Any guidance would be appreciated!

-- EDIT --

Here is the code for the "table" even though it does not actually display the table tags. This is where the account numbers appeared. I changed them to "111111" and "222222" respectively.

```
</table>

<div class="normalHeader xsmall" style="color:'CE0000'; background-color: white;">

    Mandatory Event: No Responses Required for this event <br/>

</div>





        <table width="98%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="4">

    <tr>

        <td>

            &nbsp;

        </td>

    </tr>

    <tr bgcolor="EEEEEE">

        <td class="normalHeader medium" align="left" colspan="7">

            Account Details

        </td>

    </tr>

    <tr bgcolor="EFEFEF">

        <td class="normalHeader xsmallAlternate" style="background-color: #EFEFEF;">

            Account

        </td>

        <td width="100">

            &nbsp;

        </td>

        <td align="center" class="normalHeader xsmallAlternate" width="20%" nowrap="true" style="background-color: #EFEFEF;" colspan="3">

            Holding Quantity

        </td>

        <td width="100">

            &nbsp;

        </td>

        <td class="normalHeader xsmallAlternate" nowrap="true" style="background-color: #EFEFEF;">

            Account Deadline

        </td>

    </tr>



        <tr class="xsmall">

        <td nowrap="true">

            11111111111

                    </td>

        <td>&nbsp;</td>

        <td width="100">

            &nbsp;

        </td>

        <td align="right" nowrap="true">

            25,000

        </td>

        <td width="100">

            &nbsp;

        </td>

        <td>&nbsp;</td>

        <td style="font-weight: bold;">



        </td>

    </tr>

        <tr class="xsmall">

        <td nowrap="true">

            11111111111

                    </td>

        <td>&nbsp;</td>

        <td width="100">

            &nbsp;

        </td>

        <td align="right" nowrap="true">

            50,000

        </td>

        <td width="100">

            &nbsp;

        </td>

        <td>&nbsp;</td>

        <td style="font-weight: bold;">



        </td>

    </tr>

        <tr class="xsmall">

        <td nowrap="true">

            222222222222

                    </td>

        <td>&nbsp;</td>

        <td width="100">

            &nbsp;

        </td>

        <td align="right" nowrap="true">

            50,000

        </td>

        <td width="100">

            &nbsp;

        </td>

        <td>&nbsp;</td>

        <td style="font-weight: bold;">



        </td>

    </tr>

        <tr class="xsmall">

        <td nowrap="true">

            111111111111

                    </td>

        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="100">

        &nbsp;

    </td>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a bummer, but not suprising since there's a lot going on here. Let's try a different approach. Here's an example that does not involve Excel or Outlook. I'm doing this for clarity since the Excel and Outlook stuff is gumming up the works. I'll let you decide how you'd like to plug it into your existing function.

Please get rid of any of my previous code and create a new module within Excel. (Assuming you're using Excel from the looks of the code)

**Paste the following function into your new module;** *it just returns a string that simulates the html body of an outlook mail item. The table is in the same format as the one you provided.*

```
Function GetTestHTML() As String
  'This respresents the e-mail's html body; use the e-mails html body for the real thing
  Dim strOut As String
  strOut = "<html><body>"
  strOut = strOut & "<div>Some Random Text in a div in made up html. Can be anything really.</div>"

  strOut = strOut & "<table>"
  strOut = strOut & "<tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>" 'first tr is just blank
  strOut = strOut & "<tr><td>Account Details</td></tr>" '2nd tr is 'Account Details'
  strOut = strOut & "<tr><td>Account</td><td>Holding Quantity</td><td>Account Deadline</td></tr>" '3rd tr is the column headers
  strOut = strOut & "<tr><td>11111111111</td><td>25,000</td><td>&nbsp</td></tr>" 'here's the first real data row
  strOut = strOut & "<tr><td>11111111111</td><td>50,000</td><td>&nbsp</td></tr>"
  strOut = strOut & "<tr><td>222222222222</td><td>50,000</td><td>&nbsp</td></tr>"
  strOut = strOut & "<tr><td>333333333333</td><td>75,000</td><td>&nbsp</td></tr>"
  strOut = strOut & "</table>"
  strOut = strOut & "</body></html>"
  GetTestHTML = strOut
End Function
```

**Now, please paste the following into the new module AFTER the End Function of the previous function.** *This contains the variables and functionality that will go into your main function, but you'll need to play with it in order to have it meet your needs. The comments and MsgBoxes should help identify what's going on so you can do just that.*

```
Function TestHtmlTableReplace()
  Dim nTableStart As Long, nTableEnd As Long
  Dim strTableOrg As String, strTableNew As String

  Dim strHTMLBody As String
  Dim strAccount As String

  strAccount = "222222222222" 'this value represents current account number; use the excel range account number for the real thing
  strHTMLBody = GetTestHTML 'This respresents the e-mail's html body; use the e-mails html body for the real thing

  '>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> First we isolate the TABLE block >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>

  'As you already do, we are banking on the given account number being included somewhere in the body of the html
  'not only in the body, but within a TABLE object; if it's not, then we are SOL!

  'get the pos of your account number which is in the middle of a table object
  nTableStart = InStr(1, strHTMLBody, strAccount)

  'now get the pos of the start of the table object by going in reverse from the starting pos of the previous instr
  'checking using uppercase because the source case is unknown
  nTableStart = InStrRev(UCase(strHTMLBody), "<TABLE") 'leaving out the ending > incase there are other things in the tag

  'now get the end of the table object
  'checking using uppercase because the source case is unknown
  nTableEnd = InStr(nTableStart, UCase(strHTMLBody), "</TABLE>") + Len("</TABLE>")

  'save the original table in a string so you can replace it with the new table later
  strTableOrg = Mid(strHTMLBody, nTableStart, nTableEnd - nTableStart)
  MsgBox "This is our table isolated from the HTML." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "We are going to replace it with a modified version that only shows rows with the given account number" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & strTableOrg
  '<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< First we isolate the TABLE block <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

  '>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> Now we modify the table block and replace the original HTML >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
  strTableNew = GetUpdatedTable(strTableOrg, strAccount)
  MsgBox "This is our modified table." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Now all we have to do is replace the original table with this one in our HTML:" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & strTableNew

  MsgBox "The Original HTML:" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & strHTMLBody
  strHTMLBody = Replace(strHTMLBody, strTableOrg, strTableNew)
  MsgBox "This is the Modified HTML: " & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & strHTMLBody

End Function
```

**Now, paste the following function into the new module AFTER the End Function of the previous function.** *This is just the table replace function that should remain as is. It should continue to work fine on it's own unless 'they' change the format of the html in the e-mails*

```
Function GetUpdatedTable(ByRef strTableOrg As String, ByRef strAccount As String) As String
  'now we have the table isolated and can play around until the desired results are acheived
 ' On Error GoTo ErrHandler
  Dim strTable As String
  Dim nStart As Long, nEnd As Long
  Dim strTRBlock As String

 'first tr is just blank
  nStart = InStr(1, strTableOrg, "<tr")
  If nStart < 1 Then Exit Function 'couldnt find it
  nStart = nStart + Len("<tr")

 '2nd tr is 'Account Details'
  nStart = InStr(nStart, strTableOrg, "<tr")
  If nStart < 1 Then Exit Function 'couldnt find it
  nStart = nStart + Len("<tr")

  '3rd tr is the column headers
  nStart = InStr(nStart, strTableOrg, "<tr")
  If nStart < 1 Then Exit Function 'couldnt find it
  nEnd = InStr(nStart, strTableOrg, "</tr>") + Len("</tr>")

  'we now have the first part of the table preserved
  strTable = Left(strTableOrg, nEnd - 1)

  'ditching that preserved part from what we do next.; all trs should have class="xsmall")
  strTableOrg = Trim(Replace(strTableOrg, strTable, ""))

  nStart = 1
  Do

    nStart = InStr(nStart, strTableOrg, "<tr")
    If nStart < 1 Then Exit Do

    nEnd = InStr(nStart, strTableOrg, "</tr>") + Len("</tr>")
    strTRBlock = Trim(Mid(strTableOrg, nStart, nEnd - nStart))

    'see if the account number is in this tr block
    If InStr(1, strTRBlock, strAccount) > 0 Then

      strTable = strTable & strTRBlock 'it was found so add this to the resulting table; we dont care about the block if it wasnt found
    End If

    nStart = nEnd

  Loop

  'add the </table> part since it wasnt accounted for
  strTable = strTable & "</table>"

  GetUpdatedTable = strTable
ErrHandler:
  If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    MsgBox Err.Description, vbExclamation, "Error " & Err.Number
  End If

End Function
```

Finally, click somewhere in the body of the TestHtmlTableReplace() function and run the code. Happy coding and a very happy 4th!

Comment: Wow! Thank you for that in depth answer. You obviously put a lot of time into my problem, and I really apprecaite that. I won't be able to try this out until Wednesday (that will be the next time I'm in the office) but I will keep you updated on how it all works out. One question though, will this still function properly if there are multiple <table> tags in the email? I think the header of the email may include a set of table tags even though it does not really contain any data.

Comment: I tried to insert this code into my module. I inserted the first snippet of code on the very top and inserted the function in the middle near where I call the .Forward command. I got immediate errors regarding "Object not defined"

Comment: Hey JGoldz75, I just caught the great question about the multiple <table> tags. The code to isolate the desired table assumes that the account number is somewhere in it, so it will pick up the first <table> that has the account number and disregard any others. Hopefully the account numbers are pretty unique or there will be problems. (e.g. not likely to have more than one 'ZZZZ357363563', but if it's '50' then there could be trouble.) The edit i just did will allow you to play around with different HTML scenerios so you can test the results.

Comment: Genius. I apologize but I will be on vacation until the 15th and won't be able to work with this answer until then. I will let you know how it goes when I get back! Sorry you have to wait so long for an answer. Your efforts are not in vain! This code worked fine in a new module and I understand how the comments and the MsgBox's are working and the message you are trying to send. Have a great holiday weekend!

Comment: I have been messing with this today at work. The way my code is working though, I'm not sure this will work exactly the way I'd like it too. I use SendKeys to Forward the original message to whoever it needs to go to and I also use SendKeys to send a generic message that says "no action is required". I believe this code is actually changing the original email to only include one account, but I need the HTMLbody to change in the response only. I think the best bet would be to figure somehow export the whole original email into a txt file, use code to capture the required account number

Comment: and the required value next to that number and save it to a variable, and then use code to delete the body of the email after the "Account Details ,Account, Holding Quantity, Account Deadline" parts, and then just insert the variable back into the end of the email along with the rest of the stuff that was deleted. I will give you credit for the answer though, even if it's not exactly what I will use since you put so much effort into it, and it may help someone who needs to alter that original email. 

Thanks so much for all of the efforts and help!

Comment: Hi JGoldz75, I hope you had a restful vacation. First off, thanks for the credit...I'm just trying to give a little back from all of the usefull information I've gotten from this site. I here you and that's why I modified to a more generic modulated solution to be utilized in whatever fashion that fits your needs. Remember, the functions don't know or care where the text is comming from or going to. It's up to you to decide how to utilize to fit your needs. There are so many ways to accomplish what you are trying to do that I dare not tread on the outlook side. I will say this though...

Comment: ...ahh heck, I was going to warn about using SendKeys because it's unpredictable, but then I remembered that Outlook will popup a warning message if you try and send using the mailitem object...there are alternatives to SendKeys, but I'm guessing that would be off topic...so n/m and thanks again :)